# substitute only the string concatenate with digits

Tags: awk, sed

I've tried to substitute the concatenate E with digits (i.e. `E1234`) into `#E1234`

input

```
0007 EVENT E0010 RELEASE RESP. 
EVENT STARt WITH
E1010 
  E2014
DE014
```

so by using this command, it should remove only the string with digits.

```
sed '/E[0-9]/ s/E/\#E/g' input
```

```
0007 #EV#ENT #E0010 R#EL#EAS#E R#ESP. 
EVENT STARt WITH
#E1010 
  #E2014
D#E014
```

It should output something like this. Let me know what you think.

```
0007 EVENT #E0010 RELEASE RESP. 
EVENT STARt WITH
#E1010 
  #E2014
D#E014
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/E[0-9]/#&/g' file
```

Prepend a `#` to the letter `E` followed by a digit.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` could you please try following. This will look for either small e or capital letter E with 1 or more occurrences of digits.(In case you don't need to keep `e` in regex then keep only E in regex in following code)

```
awk '{gsub(/[eE][0-9]+/,"#&")} 1'  Input_file
```

To make changes in Input_file itself append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file`